# 401 error on the terminal when trying to access the twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

My code looks like the following in python and I have been getting this error.

```
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

I was following this tutorial on this link on how to mine data from twitter and do some analysis based on that.
The error is this

```
samuel@samuel-Satellite-C850-B908:~/twitter_demo$ python twitter_streaming.py
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
```

It keeps printing 401 line by line. What is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look up HTTP error 401

Answer (score 0):

Check your system time, update / sync it with a global time server if needed. Twitter often throws a 401 Unauthorized if your system is off by even a few minutes.

Edit: PS - I assume you have valid access tokens!